# Check my queue jobs and restart the calculations that do not finish right

Tags: bash, submit, restart

I submit some calculations with some science programs in a external machine that has a job queue system. In many cases, the program crashes or not finishes right in the intrinsic calculation time of the supercomputer. So, I want to make a bash script that checks if my program is still running or not, and when the program ends, it checks the output file to see if it ends right or not. To do this last part, the output file when finishes correctly has a characteristic line, for example "Your program ends correctly". So, it can be used to check this last point.
I was thinking to use the job's queue list to check if my jobs are running or not, but I don't know how to check periodically until it has finished. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some ideas from where to pull more information that can help you: `watch`, `cron`, `sleep`, `while`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case for the `while some_command` loop. For example, if your program is the last one backgrounded by the current script the PID will be available in `$!`, and you can do this:

```
while kill -0 $!
do
    sleep 1m # Or some other amount of time
done
```

To check whether the last line of the file contains "Your program ended correctly":

```
tail -n1 output.log | grep 'Your program ended correctly'
```